# How to edit the GridView and Update values if the GridView is user defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` which is completely user defined. The first column of the `GridView` is from the `ListBox1`. The headers are defined using `ListBox2`.
[image]
 There fore I need to update rows of the `GridView` with some integer value and make sure the `Gridview` holds that value until a button is clicked.

Once the button is clicked I want to read each columns of the `GridView` that has values entered and create a table in the database with the headers names as columns and just replicate the `GridView` as table in database.

I have attached a screenshot of my `GridView`. Kindly help me fix this problem.

Comment: So what is the problem here? Also, there might be better options available  than creating tables at run-time in the db if you could throw some light as to why you are doing what you are doing.

Comment: My problem here is I click on Edit and edit the row and click on update the row is not getting updated.. I want code for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 key things to implement UPDATE logic in a GridView

1. In the GridView markup, you have to add an eventhandler for `OnRowUpdating` event
   `<asp:GridView ID="XXX" runat="Server" .....
                  OnRowUpdating="UpdateRecord" ..........>`
2. Then you need to implement this `"UpdateRecord"` method referred above with your custom code which will basically retrieve the data from the grid row and update it to your datasource
   You can refer to some sample code of how this can be achieved [here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article29.aspx)

To point out again, in your case, since you want to dynamically create the table as well, you will need to additionally do that as well. Personally, i have no clue why you would go with such a design but in absence of any information, i assume you know best.

Comment: I am first a fall not able to update the `GridView` with what ever values I have entered. And about the design part I am doing what ever my boss has asked me to do. When it comes to C# I am in nursery. So I cant figure out any other efficient ways to get rid of this. Kindly help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you help me further. How to update the `GridView` and replicate the same `GridView` in the database....???